# Can I publish multiple theme in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopify. Is there a chance that I can publish multiple shopify theme at once? I know this question is super noob but I really need a help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you exactly need to implement?

Comment: @HymnZ, Coz when I go to the themes page I see bunch of themes with customize and publish buttons.

Comment: You can only have one running "theme" at a time. Having said that you can set different templates for different pages. Search for "shopify multiple templates", you'll find multiple resources guiding you.

Answer (score 1):

The published theme refers to the "Live" theme that is what customers will see when looking at your site. The rest are just stored on the server for your internal use, and can be published if you wish to replace your live theme.